# Run Minecraft Server using OSX Lion Server?

Tags: osx-server

Is it possible to run a Minecraft server using an OSX Lion server? I know that this is a very basic question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You don't even need to have the Sever edition of Lion. Here is how:

1. Download minecraft_server.jar from the [Minecraft website](http://www.minecraft.net/download)
2. Open terminal and paste the command listed below (there should be a space after -jar
3. Drag the minecraft_server.jar into the Terminal window and type nogui. Then hit enter. Your server should start up.

Read [this article](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Setting_up_a_server) on the Minecraft Wiki for more information.

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar
```

Comment: Command shown is missing a leading "java" and a trailing "minecraft_server.jar"

Comment: @Olie - I fixed what you suggested. Next time, hit "Improve answer" and make the changes there (speeds up the process)

Comment: Also, the missing "minecraft_server.jar" is normal. If you follow the instructions posted, it inserts the full file path.

Answer (score 0):

Sure is

Just down load the .jar sever file and run it with command line that minecraft suggests

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you add some detail to this answer? Where can the .jar and command be found? Are there any other installation or configuration steps? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run the Minecraft server on Mac OS X Lion Server as well as on Mac OS X Lion. Keep in mind that Mac OS X Lion Server is an additional package of server applications, services and tools on top of OS X Lion. You need it if you want [any of the services](http://www.apple.com/macosx/server/features/) provided by OS X Server.

If you intend to run the Minecraft server at all times, **the proper solution** is to start it as a deamon using launchd. **[See here](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Create_a_Mac_OS_X_startup_daemon)**.

This allows you to always get the Minecraft server running on system startup without having to open a user session. This way if your computer crashes and reboots you don't have to relaunch the server or login to automatically launch it.